# To update single field in a document on MongoDB, what is the best method? update or patch hook in feathersjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, feathersjs, feathers-hook

I'm try to update mongodb document in single field, I have doubt to which method i want to use either patch or update using feathers framework, give an example how we can do it.

```
const { authenticate } = require('feathers-authentication').hooks;

module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [ authenticate('jwt') ],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },

  after: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },

  error: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`update` will replace the entire document. To merge with existing data `patch` should be used. This is documented [here](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html#patchid-data-params) and [here](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/common.html#adapterpatchid-data-params---promise) with the following example:

```
app.service('messages').patch(1, {
  text: 'A patched message'
}).then(message => console.log(message));

const params = {
  query: { read: false }
};

// Mark all unread messages as read
app.service('messages').patch(null, {
  read: true
}, params);
```